# How to set VoiceOver accessibility language for ALL elements at once?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, accessibility, voiceover

I can set the language for every single element through

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *accessibilityLanguage
```

and I remember that somewhere I came across a mention about a way to set the language for ALL elements at once. I think it was not a category on NSObject but an API that Apple provided. Can'T find it anymore.

Is there an API or was it really just the NSObject category?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the accessibility language of your complete app by setting the `accessibilityLanguage` property of `[UIApplication sharedApplication]`. So for setting the language to US English, use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setAccessibilityLanguage:@"en-US"];`

Thanks to zavié: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21284038/2728579